# R dates change to NA while formatting - how to avoid this?

Tags: r

I'm having an issue where during re-runs of a code, dates when reformatting to dates becomes NA.

The initial import contains M/D/YYYY dates but then I convert these into r-style dates. During re-runs of this code, I need something that can handle identify if the initial dates are in M/D/YYYY (from .csv) or the correct "%m/%d/%Y" format and then proceed from there.

I feel like these should be a simple workaround to this.

Sample code:

```
NAV <- data.frame(Date = c("1/2/2014", "1/3/2014", "1/6/2014", "1/7/2014", "1/8/2014"), Value = c(502, 503, 505, 504, 501))

NAV[,1] <- as.Date(NAV[,1], "%m/%d/%Y")

LatestAMAlert <- paste("As of 01/09/2014")

NAV[length(NAV[,1])+1,1] <- as.Date(substr(LatestAMAlert,7,16), "%m/%d/%Y")

NAV[length(NAV[,2]),2] <- 509

write.csv(NAV, file = "NAV.csv", row.names = FALSE)

NAV <- read.csv("NAV.csv", 1)

NAV[,1] <- as.Date(NAV[,1], "%m/%d/%Y")


LatestAMAlert <- paste("As of 01/10/2014")

NAV[length(NAV[,1])+1,1] <- as.Date(substr(LatestAMAlert,7,16), "%m/%d/%Y")

NAV[length(NAV[,2]),2] <- 510
```

Comment: Please provide `LatestAMAlert` so your code is runnable.

Comment: When you write a CSV with a date column, dates are written in standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You can (a) use the default format for `as.Date()` after reading in a previously formatted CSV, (b) save in a format like RDS that preserves classes so no conversion is needed (see `?saveRDS`), (c) convert the `Date` column to a `character` column in your format before writing to CSV, then convert it back with the same code. (b) is a great choice if only R needs to read these files. (a) is a good choice if you need to be able to open the files in other programs too. (c) doesn't sound very good.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
LatestAMAlert <- "As of 01/10/2014"
NAV <- read.csv("NAV.csv")
newEntry <- data.frame(Date = as.factor(as.Date(substr(LatestAMAlert,7,16), "%m/%d/%Y")),
                       Value = 510)
NAV <- rbind(NAV,newEntry)

       Date Value
1 2014-01-02   502
2 2014-01-03   503
3 2014-01-06   505
4 2014-01-07   504
5 2014-01-08   501
6 2014-01-09   509
7 2014-01-10   510
```

When you `read.csv`, the `Date` column is a factor, and by providing a new factor to append, the date is not converted (I think ...).